# RK4 Approximation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation:

$y'=xy^2-(y/x)$ with the initial value $y(1)=1$.

I'm trying to get a 4-digit approximation of this differential equation for $y(1.5)$ but I have thus far been unable to understand the RK4 method. I have been trying to understand how you would solve this without a computing system and so far I have been unable to figure this out.

Anything would help. Thanks!

Comment: For me it is not clear what you actually want. Do you need to use the RK4 method? If not, why did you choose RK4?

Comment: Well actually it doesn't matter. Since you [don't care to appreciate help](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/464506/john-smith?tab=questions), I will not waste time here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set $h=0.5$. Then compute per cook-book recipe using rounding to 2 digits
\begin{align}
k_1&=hf(x,y)&&=0.5f(1,1)&&=0\\
k_2&=hf(x+0.5h, y+0.5k_1)&&=0.5f(1.25, 1)&&=0.22\\
k_3&=hf(x+0.5h, y+0.5k_2)&&=0.5f(1.25, 1.1)&&=0.5(1.25\cdot 1.21-1.1⋅0.8)=0.32\\
k_2&=hf(x+h, y+k_3)&&=0.5f(1.5,1.32)&&=0.5(2.73-0.9)=0.87\\ \\
y(1.5)&\approx 1+(k_1+2k_2+2k_3+k_4)/6&&=1+1.95/6&&=1.32
\end{align}

---

The `double` computation gives

```
k1 = 0.0
k2 = 0.225
k3 = 0.32853515625
k4 = 0.8809091939608258
1+(k1+2k2+2k3+k4)/6 = 1.331329917743471
```

---

The exact solution results from $u(x)=\dfrac1{xy(x)}$, $u(1)=1$
$$
(xu)'=u+xu'=-\frac{y'}{y^2}=-x+u\\\implies u'=-1,\; u=2-x \\\implies y(x)=\frac{1}{2x-x^2}
$$
so that $y(\frac32)=\frac43=1.3333...$